# Segmentation fault on Ubuntu while running fine on Windows, programmed in c

Tags: c

I am writing a small oscillatory motion program that would run on Ubuntu and Windows. 
After completing part of the program (major part) I tried to test it on windows, works fine (working with Pelles C)
Then, i copied my data on the Ubunutu computer, Running on a virtual Machine (VMware Workstation). 
i compiled it fine using GCC and crashes with "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. 
Output before crashing:

```
Simulation Starting...
Creating Containers.....
Done!
Initializing Containers.....
Initializing Container
Done!...
Initializing Container
Done!...
Initializing Container
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
--------------------------------
```

Part of zDA.c, the function required to initialize vectors before using in simulation

```
int InitializeArray (DATA *item) {
    printf("\nInitializing Container");
    item->num_allocated = 0;
    item->num_elements = 0;
    item->the_array = NULL;
    printf("\nDone!...");
    if (!item->the_array) {
    return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

While calling the function, snippet from zSim.c

```
int Simulate(SIMOPT so,PRINTOPT po) {
    printf("\nSimulation Starting...\nCreating Containers...");
    //Create Data Objects
        //vectors
    DATA Theta,Omega,T;
    DATA *pTheta = &Theta;
    DATA *pOmega = &Omega;
    DATA *pT = &T;

        //Initial Values
    int method = so.method;
    float g = so.g;
    float l = so.l;
    float itheta = so.theta;
    float iomega = so.omega;
    float dt = so.dt;
    float df = so.df;
    float dw = so.dw;
    float q = so.q;
    float maxtime = so.maxtime;

        //backend variables
    float i = 0; //Simulation Counter
    int k=0;     //Counter to Count array size;
    int kmax = 0;
    float th,thi,om,omi,t,ti; //Simulation variables

    int gt,go,pl,mat;
    printf("..");
    printf("\nDone!\nInitializing Containers...");
    printf("..");
    //Initialize Containers
    InitializeArray(pTheta);
    InitializeArray(pOmega);
    InitializeArray(pT);           //**FOR SOME REASON, it stops working here -_- 
    printf("DONE! NIT");           //It worked fine on windows, there are no dependencies.
    th = pTheta->the_array[0];     
    om = pOmega->the_array[0];
    t = pT->the_array[0];
```

i don't get why it worked on windows, didn't on ubuntu, either the compiler on Pelles fixed something for me, or my virtual machine is going crazy,
i mean... it already Initialized 2 out of 3 arrays, what's wrong with the third :)"?

Comment: Generally it's not the compiler or OS who's crazy, so that leaves only one susepct... ahem ;). What is the exact line where it seg faults?

Comment: When you get different results using substantially different platforms, undefined behavior is a frequent culprit.  Run it in a debugger and find out exactly where it's crashing.

Comment: for what purpose is `InitializeArray` of type int? should you not check the return val?and the `InitializeArray` always returns `-1` because `the_array` is initialized `NULL`.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization looks like it would not crash.  But the code immediately following it looks suspect.  The array has not been initialized (well ... it is initialized, but it is initialized to NULL), yet the following code accesses it:

```
th = pTheta->the_array[0];
```

Comment: thanks for all the help... 
I will edit and add part of the code that does fix the Null thing.